# How to pass optional function parameter

Tags: python, function, arguments

I am currently learning python and tried to implement chess.
(I've already done this in multiple different languages)

```
class Board:

    def __init__(self):
        self._reset()

    def _reset(self, func=Board.default_layout):
        self.values = [[0 for x in range(8)] for i in range(8)]
        self.currentPlayer = 1
        func(self.values)

    @staticmethod
    def default_layout(values):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = Board()
```

The idea of the reset method is to reset the board. The pieces on it will be removed and a function will be called that places the pieces on the board in the initial layout.

There are chess versions, where there are different starting layouts. Therefor I wanted to make it an optional parameter with the default method: `default_layout(self)`

However this code does not compile and I would like to know where my problem is.

I get the error message:

```
NameError: name 'default_layout' is not defined
```

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error message?

Comment: yeah... NameError: name 'default_layout' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `def _reset(self, func=Board.default_layout):` is being evaluated as part of the definition of `Board`, so `Board.default_layout` is not defined yet.

You could make `default_layout` an ordinary function instead of a static method. It needs to be defined before you use it.

```
def default_layout(values):
    ... whatever

class Board:
    ...
    def _reset(self, func=default_layout):
        ...
```

Or, if it *must* be a static method, don't try and reference it inside the function declaration. You can reference it inside the function *body*, because the body isn't executed until the function is actually called.

```
    def _reset(self, func=None):
        if func is None:
            func = Board.default_layout
```

Comment: Thank you! Does python define things from top to the bottom?

Because this would not work if the function default_layout would be written after the class.

Comment: Oh okay that explains it. Thanks for your answer! I will accept it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @khelwood's answer, you can also use a `lambda` function instead if you prefer to keep `default_layout` a static method of the `Board` class.

Change:

```
def _reset(self, func=Board.default_layout):
```

to

```
def _reset(self, func=lambda values: Board.default_layout(values)):
```

Comment: That is a lovely solution! Thank you :)